# Android SurfaceView and returning a bitmap containing all draw calls

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm working with a SurfaceView so I can create a separate thread just for drawing.
My problem is how to obtain a bitmap of the current pixels on the screen for which I draw to the canvas.
Here's some code for a basic overview:

```
class SurfaceRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Thread thread;
    Canvas canvas;

    public SurfaceRenderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder(); //holder for Canvas so I can draw in my thread
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        // thread has started
        while(true) {
            if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                // do some drawing...
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

}

So I want to get a superior bitmap encapsulating all the bitmaps that I have drawn to the canvas of my SurfaceView. Because there is no method getBitmap() which returns a bitmap of my whole entire SurfaceView I need some other way to achieve such. Please help me out here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your example fails, because lockCanvas  works only in UI thread, which is a real pain, so I never use SurfaceView.

But since you insist on using SurfaceView, here is the hint: you create your own bitmap draw everything in it and supply it to SurfaceHolder just for drawing. This is how you have the bitmap available to your app. This may be less efficient than drawing on SurfaceHolder, because graphic acceleration doesn't work in this case.

The example assumes that the thread is initialized **after** the surface is ready, so you know width and size of the view. (You probably should use AsyncTask instead of Thread, but I am rather old-fashioned :) )

```
public class DrawingThread extends Thread  {
     Activity activity;
     SurfaceView view;;
     Bitmap backBuffer;
     boolean bufferProcessed;
     public DrawingThread(Activity activity, SurfaceView view) {
          this.activity = activity;
          this.view = view;
          backBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);          
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
          try {
               for (;;) {
                   Canvas canv = new Canvas(backBuffer);
                   // Draw on canvas  
                   .....................................  
                   bufferProcessed = false;

                   activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                          SurfaceHolder holder = view.getHolder();
                          Canvas hCanv = holder.lockCanvas();
                          hCanv.drawBitmap(backBuffer, 0f, 0f, null);
                          holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(hCanv);
                          synchronized(DrawingThread.this) {
                               bufferProcessed = true;
                               DrawingThread.this.notify(); 
                          }
                       }
                   });  

                   while(!bufferProcessed) 
                      synchronized(this) {wait();}

               }
           }catch(InterruptedException ex) {}


     }


}
```

Comment: How does my example fail I have written a full fledged game using that type of initialization for my canvas?

Comment: Your answer will definitely suffice my needs. But I still don't agree to the words that you said, that lockCanvas() only works in the UI thread, on the contrary a SurfaceView is meant to be a separate process for drawing calls, rather than hogging the UI thread. And the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method can be overridden to draw to the UI thread, if you aren't hosting that much operations.

Comment: Is there a way to use the canvas.setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) for all the drawing calls to be set to the bitmap parameter?